# How to clear the selection in an EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textselection

How do you programmatically remove the selection from an `EditText`?  I've tried:

```
myEditText.setSelection(selectionEnd);
```

but that just creates a selection of 0 length at the end of the current selection.  I've also tried `Selection.removeSelection(mySpannable)`, and it just puts an empty selection at the beginning of the text.

Comment: do you want to clear text from edit text

Comment: no, just cancel the text selection highlighting

Comment: Have you got your answer ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Calling `myEditText.clearFocus();`. I think that's what you need

Comment: This also hides the cursor. What if I want to remove the selection but keep the blinking cursor?

Answer (score 3):

To move selection to top:

```
edit_text.setSelection(0);
```

To move selection to bottom:

```
edit_text.setSelection(edit_text.getText().length());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sendText);
String text = message.getText().toString();
message.setText(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simulate a tap gesture if you want to keep the textview focused:

```
public static void clearTextSelection(TextView view) {
        MotionEvent evt = MotionEvent.obtain(0, 0, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, -1, -1, 0);
        view.dispatchTouchEvent(evt);
        evt.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
        view.dispatchTouchEvent(evt);
//      evt.setSource(100);
//      if(view.hasSelection()) view.clearFocus();
        evt.recycle();
    }
```