# Android - How put a backgroud text in a EditText?

Tags: android, xml, text, background, android-edittext

I have putted a EditText in a XML. 
I want to use this EditText to the user insert his name.

I want that appears in this EditText the text "Insert the Name", but when the user click on it, the text "Insert the Name" disappear, so the user don't need to delete the phrase "Insert the Name".

I want the same "Event name" effect in this image:

[image]

What is needed to do in the EditText to get this effect?
Thanks!

Comment: is called to hint `android:hint="Event name"` set in editText

Comment: Put this In your XML 's EditText android:hint="Insert the Name"

Comment: Thanks very much, i have found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add hint in your Editext in your xml File

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Insert Name"/>
```

Comment: thanks very much man! <3

Answer (score 0):

This will be helpful: 
[How to clear the selection in an EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534039/how-to-clear-the-selection-in-an-edittext)

do it programatically by using:

```
myEditText.clearFocus();
```

which fills it up with actual text

or xml:

```
android:hint="text here"
```

which is unselectable greyed out 'hint' text you want

Comment: thanks man for your support